# React Native - Import css / js in WebView

Tags: css, react-native, cdn, node-modules

I have a WebView with CSS and JS links in the head section. They are all CDN links so everything works fine.

Is it possible to import that CSS / JS from the node_modules folder directly?

So for example if I want to import bootstrap's CSS into the webview

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

works, but 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css">`

does not work (lets say for testing purposes i put the file in the same folder as my component with the webview)

Please let me know if you need to see more code or the question is unclear. Also, bootstrap is just used as an example here. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can import it as normal html:

```
var bootstrap = `<!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                  <head>
                      <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                      <style type="text/css">
                      img{
                          max-width: 100%;
                      }
                      </style>
                  </head>
                  <body>X</body></html>`;
bootstrap = bootstrap.replace('X', html);
return (
 <WebView
      source={{html: bootstrap}}
      style={{marginTop: 20}}
   />
);
```

where html is your content, and you have to copy the style or like it and customize to your need. It worked for me nicely

Comment: Is there no solution that avoids just jamming all the CSS inline? I would like to have syntax highlighting and formatting...